# Logical operator can only be applied to Boolean

Tags: apex, trigger

```
if (contact.Birthdate != null && contact.Active_Contracts__c >0
       && contact.AccountId != null && contact.Pension_Insurance__c != null &&
        ((contact.Health_Insurance__c = 'statutory' && contact.Statutory_Health_Insurance_Addition__c != null)||
         (contact.Health_Insurance__c != 'statutory' && contact.Private_Health_Insurance_Amount__c != null))
        && contact.Age__c != null && contact.Child_Tax_Allowance__c != null && contact.MailingState != null
        && contact.Church_Tax__c != null && contact.Monthly_Gross_Income__c != null && contact.Tax_Class__c != null)
```

Code won't get saved! Everything looks okay to me. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is `contact.Health_Insurance__c = 'statutory'`

`=` =>  assignment operator
`==` => equality comparison operator
`!=` => not equal comparison operator

You want to use the equality comparison operator here

Comment: You are right! I missed it. Thanks